# In PHP's bind_param, any reason I can't define all columns as a type String?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got some tables I insert into with 40 to 50 columns - the type definitions are a nightmare - and look like this: 'ississsiisssisiiisssssiissssiisssssssiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'

When I add a column, I have no idea where to put the next letter.  If I screw it up, obviously strings get converted into numbers (which makes no sense).  But numbers handled as strings seem to have no problems with MySQL.  Does anyone else see anything I should be worried about?

see bind_param docs here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: isisisisisssiiiisiiii? Sorry, your question is a tiny nightmare too. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @deceze these are the definitions for the placeholders in the mysqli statement. s is for string, i is for integer. When you have a statement like `select foo from bar where a=? and b=?`, every `?` corresponds to one letter/type in the bind param call.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for jumping in there Gordon - exactly what I meant.

Comment: Oh boy... @Gordon Thanks for the clarification. @Arbol Any chance you could switch to a saner db schema and/or database interface (guessing not)?

Comment: This is a problem even on smaller queries.  I have a situation the other day where I have something like SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = ? AND name = ? AND place = ?  --- the proper type definition was 'iss' but I swapped them to 'sis' and caused myself undo levels of harm and annoyance until I spotted the tiny bug.

Comment: @Arbol you can mitigate bugs introduced by changing queries by unit-testing your code. You'd still have to write iiiissisiisii but at least you'd fail early then and know any errors relate to a recent change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the advice

- build an array that holds your table columns and its type

such as

```
 $table_columns = array('NAME_OF_COLUMN_1'=>'i',
 'NAME_OF_COLUMN_2'=>'i',
 'NAME_OF_COLUMN_3'=>'s',
 ...
```

Where there is change of your column type, update the `$table_columns`.
Where there is new addition of column, add new column into `$table_columns`.
Where there is removal of existing column, remote the existing column from `` `$table_columns ``.

After that, just

```
implode('', array_values($table_columns))
```

for binding,

to list column name

```
implode(',', array_keys($table_columns))
```

this method will reduce error prone, and easily maintain

Comment: Yes - but this doesn't answer my question about inserting all values into MySQL via PHP mysqli using string type instead of integers.

Comment: Thank you for trying to come up with a solution for me - though.  Greatly appreciated.